# how can I fix the error: unable to install updates prepared update not found /var/lib/packagekit/prepared-update in ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS?

Tags: updates

[gnome software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flicp.png) [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiUBz.png)   how can I fix the error:

```
unable to install updates prepared update not found /var/lib/packagekit/prepared-update
```

in ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS gnome software?

I've already tried to update through the terminal, but the pending packages are still not being installed.

My skills are limited, and I haven't been able to solve the problem for 3 days...

If anyone can help, thanks in advance...

Comment: You said that you have tried to update via terminal but, can you paste the output on pastebin? --> 

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f -y && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove --purge -y`

Comment: Do not use `-y` option. Always review the changes before accepting them.

Comment: Do run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and edit your question to include any errors. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the commands: sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, and it shows me that 7 packages will not be updated. Inside gnome software it shows me the error: unable to install updates prepared update not found /var/lib/packagekit/prepared-update.

Comment: please edit your question and add the full output of these commands.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, how do I get the full output of these commands?

Comment: The full output is displayed in the terminal. Copy it. Paste it into your question above. [How to edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1437675/edit)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, the system has requested a restart...
I put the images in the question, hope it's correct...

Comment: Pending updates are pending for a reason, phased updates.

Comment: Just updating, today all packages were updated without major problems.
Thanks to the community for your attention and help!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there was a [bug in GNOME's Automatic Updates that was fixed around Jul-2022](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/merge_requests/1401).

It may take a while for this fix to reach the end-users, especially if their upgrades fail...

Can try upgrading via the terminal, as suggested by [mchid](https://askubuntu.com/users/167115/mchid) -
run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Eventually, it should be able to install the fix to GNOME Automatic Updates.