# Error when updating Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04

This is the 3rd time that this same error has occurred in an Ubuntu installation with me, I have not been able to resolve it like other people on the internet who have had the same problem.

[image: app-center-screenshot]

Comment: I already tried but it didn't work for me

Comment: Duplicate of [Software center: "Prepared update not found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452772/software-center-prepared-update-not-found)